# Typing recursive function with union return type in typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, typing

I am trying to type a typescript function who adds a property to objects in nested arrays of arbitrary depth.
The runtime code is trivial in Javascript but i have been pulling my hair for the whole day to get the Typescript types to compile.

The code should take an array like this `[{}, {}]` or this `[[{},{}]]` or this `[[[{},{}]]]` and add the `marked:true` property to every object;

```
type Nested<T> = T | Array<Nested<T>>;
function markNested<T>(objOrNestedArray: Nested<T>): T {
  if (Array.isArray(objOrNestedArray)) {
    return objOrNestedArray.map(markNested);
  } else {
    return { ...objOrNestedArray, marked: true };
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what "bivariant" means in this question?  My understanding of that term in TypeScript involves [type variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), but I don't see that happening here

Comment: Don't bother with that, it's probably a misunderstanding of my part on the meaning of the word, since i have exactly zero knowledge in type theory.

Comment: I'm happy to change it to something else... did you mean "varying" or "variable" or "dependent" or something?

Comment: I meant that the function can return a union of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing the correct return type on the function.  It needed to be `Nested<T>` like the source array.  For completeness, I also added the marked property, since that might be useful to look up.

```
function markNested<T>(objOrNestedArray: Nested<T>): Nested<T & { marked: boolean }> {
  /*... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!